# Creating a post process to get data from XML file combined with a code to write .gnu file

Tags: python, xml, gnuplot

I'm a relatively new coder and could really use some help. I apologize if I don't fully describe my problem well. I am trying to write a post process / get data from XML file that will go with my code to write .gnu file. The end goal is to use this customfunctions script to produce a png file with a graph of the data from the XML file. My code is shown below.

I cannot use the: plot "MDNBR_data.dat" line because I am not able to have the file in the system and will have to have a custom code that parses the xml. All help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
def MDNBR(self):
    '''
    '''
    self.filename = "MDNBR_data.gnu"
    self.figurename = "MDNBR_data.png"

    #-- post process / get data from XML file

    #-- write code to write .gnu file

    self.output = textwrap.dedent('''\
    set terminal png size 800,600 
    set output "MDNBR_data.png" 
    set grid 
    set xlabel "Cycle" 
    set title "MDNBR-CEA Ejection" 
    set xtics (25,26,27)
    set yrange[1.1:1.4]
    plot "MDNBR_data.dat" using 1:2 title 'MDNBR' w linespoints lt 3 lw 3 pt 7 ps 1.5, "MDNBR_data.dat" u 1:3 t 'Limit' w linespoints lt 1 lw 3 pt 7 ps 1.5
    ''')
    pass


class RunGnuPlot (object):
'''
'''
def __init__ (self, gnu_filename):
    self.status = 0
```

Comment: Search for `python xml parser`